# Deleting multiple columns of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has 89 columns. Almost 40 of them are string and I just need the rest which are float and integer. How can delete all these 40 columns apart from deleting one by one?
Ps. I have some nan values in my integer and float columns. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: `df = df.select_dtypes(np.number)`

Comment: What about `df.drop(columns=['col_to_del', ...])` or `df[['col_to_keep', ...]]`?

Comment: This one is going to take a lot of time that's why I asked for a 'quick' way. For the first comment I've got an error - -> 'method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Can you paste the exact line of code you run that produced that error please?

Comment: info = house_info.select_dtypes[np.number] it was this one but I've found how to do with the answer of question that you shared

Comment: I just figured I've used wrong brackets sorry :)

Comment: yip, just needs rounded brackets `()` :)